# How to create Pentagon graphs in Android Java

Tags: java, android, graph

I've an Android assignment where I have to come up with an android app, create a design doc, and then within the next two to three weeks, create it.

My idea basically involves the use of Pentagon Graphs (not sure if thats the real name). Which allow the viewer to compare two sets of data.

for example.

Data A Str   Stm    Atk   Def
       5      4     5     2
Data B 4      3     5     5

I would like to have both graphics translucently overlayed on each other.

Any information would be great. Failing that, I could just do some piddly memo/notepad app :(

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're looking for is called a [RadarChart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart). I however don't know of any android chart library that supports them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) , a great android chart library